# What is the syntax for marquee tag from top to bottom?

Tags: html

I do not know how to use marquee with a direction from top to bottom.
I already tried  Marquee Text

Comment: Doesn't really matter since the marquee tag [is obsolete anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Comment: have a look `<marquee  behavior="scroll" direction="down">Your upward scrolling text goes here</marquee>
`

Comment: @AbdulBasit, Sir, it is only limited to a little space.

Comment: @patrickesguerra you can add `height` or `position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0`

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
<marquee direction="down">Marquee Text</marquee>
```

The possible values of direction are left, right, up & down.

Comment: It's only limited to a little space.

Comment: marquee {
                height: 100px;
            }

Comment: Use simple CSS to resize the space.

Comment: <marquee direction="down" style="height:300px">Marquee Text</marquee>